# Merging two VB.Net Projects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

we are new to Visual Basic Programing, We are working on a project, which has modules. My team worked on these modules and prepared 3 separate Visual Studio Projects. Now, I want to combine then into one Visual Studio Project for Integration purposes.
We are using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What is the question? That is, what exactly are you stuck on? What you are describing is not that difficult, as you would see if you tried. If you did try and fail, please explain where you are failing (examples and error messages included please).

Comment: I would question why you are integrating the projects together.  Do you have to do this?  Breaking a solution into separate projects usually helps maintainability.

Answer (score 4):

In the solution explorer window (Default is top right) you will need to:

1. ***Right click on your Solution***
2. go down to ***Add***
3. select **Existing Project**
4. This will pop up a windows browser window, you will need to navigate to the place that you have the files saved, then click **Open**
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for all subsequent items.

Based on what you are saying, it sounds like youll need to add references to the modules in the main project:

1. Ensure that you are viewing all files in your solution by selecting ***Show All Files*** in the Solution Explorer
2. go down to ***References***
3. click ***Add Reference*** - a window will pop up
4. in the top left, select ***Projects***
5. in the popup window ***Right click*** on the Name of the project and select ***Add Reference***

You should be good from here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear wether or not you want to add the code from the individual projects to one project or add your projects to one solution.

1. In the first instance use the project that you want to be the main project and right-click on the project and select add existing item to select the .vb module file that you want to add.
2. In the second instance create a blank solution File -> New Project -> Other Project Types -> Visual Studio Solutions -> Blank Solution, then right-click on the new solution and select Add -> Existing project to add your projects